# Convert specific pages from .docx to .pdf using Microsoft.Interop

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, office-interop

I am using the Microsoft Interop library to convert the .docx files to .pdf
Here is the code that I am using for:

```
                    Application app = new Application();
                    Document doc = app.Documents.Open(@"inputPath");
                    doc.SaveAs2(@"outputPath", WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF);
                    doc.Close();
                    app.Quit();
```

The .docx files that I am converting are 13 - 20 Pages. I need informations just for 2 first pages from each file. So, I want also to save time from the converting process.

**How to get and convert just two first pages ?**

Comment: Delete pages 3+?

Comment: @mjwills I want to convert to pdf just page 1 and 2!

Comment: So delete pages 3+. Then pages 1 and 2 will remain. Then you can save pages 1-2 as PDF.

Comment: @mjwills but I am asking for this solution xD How to do that ?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=c%23+word+remove+pages

Answer (score 0):

You can try to copy the specific word pages to a new document as a temporary document to store the content using [Application Selection.Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.selection.copy?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection.Copy);k(Copy);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=word-pia) method.

And then using [Document.SaveAs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.saveas?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word._Document.SaveAs);k(SaveAs);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.0);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=word-pia) method to save the temporary document as a PDF file.

George Hua has provided a complete code example in this [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e48b3126-941d-490a-85ee-e327bbe7e81b/convert-specific-word-pages-to-pdf-in-c?forum=worddev) you can refer to.